# "cannot access archive: No such file or directory" when installing a package using dpkg

Tags: dpkg

I have download the QQ2012's deb in downlaod files, but when I install the deb, system tell me:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i wineqq2012-20120719-longene.deb
[sudo] password for collins: 
dpkg: error processing wineqq2012-20120719-longene.deb (--install):
 cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 wineqq2012-20120719-longene.deb
```

Comment: Related: [How do I install a .deb file via the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40779/how-do-i-install-a-deb-file-via-the-command-line)

Answer (score 9):

The error message `No such file or directory` means that the `.deb` file does not exist, or does not exist in the current directory.

The `~` between `:` and `$` in the prompt represents the current working directory. `~` (when the next character is a `/` or, as in this case, nothing at all) is shorthand for your home directory, `/home/collins`.

You said you downloaded the `.deb` file "in download files." Assuming this means you downloaded it to your `Downloads` folder, that means it's located in `/home/collins/Downloads` rather than `/home/collins`.

So you should be able to install it by running this command:

```
sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/wineqq2012-20120719-longene.deb
```

If that doesn't work, try typing

```
sudo dpkg -i
```

without pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Add a space to the end. Then drag the file from Nautilus (the file browser) into the Terminal window. That will paste its full path. Then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are running the command from a different directory.

Open Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and make sure that the file you trying to run is listed when you do the `ls` command.

If you have downloaded the file using a web browser browser, then the file should be located in `~/Downloads`. Change the directory to your downloads folder with `cd ~/Downloads`.

Once you have made sure that `ls` lists the file, then run the command:

```
sudo dpkg -i wineqq2012-20120719-longene.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify the command the following way:

```
sudo dpkg -i ./wineqq2012-20120719-longene.deb
```

This will make `dpkg` search the package in the current folder.

BTW, you should you use `apt`, to get the pkg listed in the log files, and more:

```
sudo apt install ./wineqq2012-20120719-longene.deb
```